# when selecting a folder in sudo nautilus closes and shows tracking violation

Tags: nautilus, sudo, 22.10

hello I have a serious problem it turns out that I open sudo nautilus from the terminal (I have to make some important changes with apt) but it turns out that when opening a simple folder it closes and shows this unknown error that I have not been able to locate in Google[image]

[image]

How can I solve that

Comment: Apparently I realize that it is a bug of Ubuntu 22.10 because the error also appears on my laptop

Comment: Yes, this is a bug (assuming that Violacíon de segmento is a segfault in English). There is not much we can do about a segfault on this website. You could enter the issue on the Nautilus [bug page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus) but there are very many bugs reported already, some of which are very old.

Comment: I have reported the error here Reporting bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1994058